Make all lines same length in Slope Field
In the following slope field, how do you get all the lines to be the same length?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                scale = 0.85,
                axis lines = middle,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$M(t)$,
                enlargelimits,
                xtick = {15},
                ytick = {70},
                xmin = -0.5, xmax = 20.5,
                ymin = -0.5, ymax = 70.5,
                zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
                view = {0}{90},
                ]
                
                % Define the differential equation
                \def\DE{(40 - y) / 4}
                
                % Draw the slope field
                \addplot3[black!75, samples=15,
                quiver = {
                    u = {1/sqrt(1+(\DE)^2)},
                    v = {(\DE)/sqrt(1+(\DE)^2)},
                    scale arrows = 0.5,
                },
                domain = 0:20,
                domain y = 0:70,
                ] {0};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Provide a field with constant amount of slope, but varying angles. A simple example is a unit vector,where its orientation depends on the xy coordinates.

I want to plot dy/dx = (40 - y) / 4. Can you provide code of that slope field with lines of same length?

I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a mathematical contradiction to me, once you normalized all vectors ...

I'm asking whether it's possible, regardless of method. So, if one needs to directly plot each slope using tikz, then so be it. Even in that case, I'm still very interested in how to produce this slope field with each slope being the same length in LaTeX.

I'd like to suggest these two answers of mine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644721/140133 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643386/140133.
They show how to customize colors under normalized vectors. I'd argue this questions is more a duplicate than not suitable for Tex.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
DE=(40-y)/4;
U=1/sqrt(1+DE^2);
V=DE/sqrt(1+DE^2);
len=sqrt(U^2+V^2);
axisratio=21/71;
heightwidthratio=5/7;
}]
\begin{axis}[
width=7cm, height=5cm, scale only axis,
axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$M(t)$,
enlargelimits,
xtick={15}, ytick={70},
xmin=-0.5, xmax=20.5,
ymin=-0.5, ymax=70.5,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
view={0}{90},
]

\addplot3[
black!75,
quiver={
  u={U/len*axisratio*heightwidthratio},
  v={V/len},
  scale arrows=3,
},
samples=15,
domain=0:20, domain y=0:70,
] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


